# What User Space tools support Btrfs functionality (e.g. clone instead of copy)

Tags: gui, btrfs, tools, snapshot

I've recently been starting to work with Btrfs on Ubuntu, and have it setup as my root filesystem, as well as home filesystem. I have it configured the way apt-btrfs-tools expects, and that is working well.

Of course, there are command line tools for Btrfs to do everything.

But, what I'm wondering is, is there support in any other tools for Btrfs-specific functionality. For example:

- Clones (file 'copies' that initially don't take aditional space, but utilize the CoW feature of Btrfs to use space only as the two files are modified) - if I try to copy a file in Dolphin, Nautilus, or other GUI file management tools, will it try to do a reflink, or do they always just do full data copies?
- GUI snapshot manager? Is there a gui tool to manage snapshots (list, create, delete), revert to a previous snapshot, revert individual files/directories from a previous snapshot.
- Volume/file info - In Btrfs, traditional tools like 'du' and 'dh' do not do a great job of showing how much free space is available, or how much space a file or directory actually really use, because they are not aware of extents being shared between files (either clones, or with the same file in other snapshots). Are there any GUI file manager tools that will show info from Btrfs showing actual space used/free?

Answer (score 0):

There is timeshift-launcher and snapper-GUI to help you boot into snapshots after a crash. some more tips can be found in the [Howto](https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs) of https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs